# Postgres full text not matching partial words in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, full-text-search

I just moved from MySQL to Postgres 9.0.3.  I have a brand new app with a little data (game data).

Anyway, I can't seem to get partial words to search.  Here is my search method:

```
def self.search(query)
  conditions = <<-EOS
    to_tsvector('english', title) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', ?)
  EOS

  find(:all, :conditions => [conditions, query])    
end
```

I'm sure I need a wildcard in there but I'm just learning Postgres.

When I search for **`Shinobi`** I get the correct results:

> Alex Kidd in Shinobi World - Sega Master System
>
> Shinobi - Sega Master System
>
> Shinobi - Nintendo Entertainment System
>
> The Cyber Shinobi: Shinobi Part 2 - Sega Master System

But when I search for **`Shin`** I get nothing?

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 3):

I think that to allow prefix matching you need to use to_tsquery instead of plainto_tsquery

that says http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES

so your code could be something like

```
def self.search(query)
  conditions = <<-EOS
    to_tsvector('english', title) @@ to_tsquery('english', ?)
  EOS

  find(:all, :conditions => [conditions, query + ':*'])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a regular expression search as shown below.

```
find( :all, :conditions => [ 'name ~* ?', "SEARCH TERM" ] )
```

Comment: regex for database search could be very inefficient if you have a reasonable amount of data

Comment: @buffer, definitely agree—for a lot of data, Elasticsearch would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Append a `*` to your query string.

Search for `Shin*`.

```
def self.search(query)
  conditions = <<-EOS
    to_tsvector('english', title) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', ?)
  EOS

  find(:all, :conditions => [conditions, query.concat("*")])    
end
```

Comment: I think you have to concatenate ":*" instead of just "*".

Answer (score 0):

Use the `prefix`:

```
  pg_search_scope :search, against: [:name, :email],
    using: {tsearch: {prefix: true}}
```